# Can't sign into App store from my Macbook

Tags: mac-appstore

I'm running High Sierra on my Mbp. I want to download an app from the app store but it keeps asking me to sign in. When I sign in, nothing happens. I have tried ABSOLUTELY everything that I could find in all the forums and still nothing works! Changed DNS settings, checked certificates, erased old caches and yes, even checked my internet connection (duh?)

Don't know what else to do. updates downloads and installs properly, but I cannot see previous purchases or download any new apps. 
PS: It works fine on my iphone...

Comment: Did you try signing out then back in, Store Menu (bit of a "Microsoft test", but I've seen it work ;)

Comment: yip, I was signed in and it didn't work, so I followed the advice of signing out and signing back in again, but can't sign in anymore.

Comment: Check if you can get into Account Details in System Prefs > iCloud

Comment: Yes, I can. Everything seems legit there.

Comment: Did you logout and log back in through the iCloud sys pref or just verify that it looked OK?

Comment: I verified that everything looked okay. If I sign out and can't sign back in I'm screwed so don't wanna risk it until the issue with the app store is resolved.